# How to cascade insert child entities when child has composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am starting with JPA coming from EF and tried to do a simple master-detail insert where the child has a composite key.

The foo is inserted alright (no errors, Hibernate just printing insert into Foo statement), but the bar just gets ignored.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519025/cascading-a-child-entity-persist-operation-to-its-parent-entity) where the relation is defined in the key, but I couldn't get it to work either (same issue as with my original solution, no exceptions, just no child insert either).

My code currently looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private String fooID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter, setter,...
}

@Entity
public class Bar {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BarId id;

    public Bar(){
        this.id = new BarId();
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("fooID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooID", referencedColumnName = "fooID")
    private Foo foo;

    public void setFooId(String fooId){
        this.id.setFooId(fooId);
    }

    public void setBarNo(int barNo){
        this.id.setBarNo(barNo);
    }

    // other getter, setter,...
}

@Embeddable
public class BarId implements Serializable {
    private String fooID;
    private int barNo;

    // getter, setter, hashCode, equals,...
}

// ...
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

Foo newFoo = new Foo();
newFoo.setFooID("baz");

Bar newBar = new Bar();
newBar.setFooId(newFoo.getFooId()); // even necessary?
newBar.setBarNo(1);
newBar.setFoo(newFoo);

newFoo.getBars().add(newBar);

em.persist(newFoo);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I am using JPA 2.2 with Hibernate 5.4 if that makes any difference.

To better clarify what I'm after (for everyone who knows a little EF):

```
foo.HasKey(f => f.FooID);
foo.HasMany(f => f.Bars).WithOne(b => b.Foo).HasForeignKey(b => b.FooID);

bar.HasKey(b => new {b.FooID, b.BarNo});
```

What do I have to change to get this to work?
Or am I using JPA entirely wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: the `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` has to be put on the master side and not on the detail side of the relation like so:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
```